# Problem with array assignment in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having a problem where I have a method where I have a data structure:

```
   const req = {
  ctx: {
    emails: [],
    newInvitationDto: {
      _type: 'NewInvitationDto',
      email: 'sethborne@gmail.com',
      groupId: '12345678',
      roleIds: ['organization.doctor'],
      firstName: 'Seth',
      lastName: 'Borne',
      title: 'Doctor',
      phone: '212.555.1212',
    },
  },
};
```

that comes from `const ctx: Invitation = <Invitation>req.ctx`, So when I console log `ctx.emails` I get an empty array.

Now when I try to push the value of `email`, that is `'sethborne@gmail.com'` into the `ctx.emails` like so: `ctx.emails.push(newInvitationDto.email)` instead of getting a data structure like so:

`['sethborne@gmail.com']`

instead I get value of `1`.

I believe something is wrong with my assignment, but not sure what it is.

Comment: `.push` returns the new length of the array, maybe you are using that value accidentally? (it would be consistent with your observation).

Comment: @FelixKling, ahh, I am trying to store the email inside of the `ctx.emails` array.

Comment: Assuming that `newInvitationDto.email` is the value you claim it is, the code you have (`ctx.emails.push(newInvitationDto.email)`) will work. But the return value of `.push` is not an array. It will be `1` because the new length of the array is `1`.

Comment: @FelixKling, how do I ensure the return value is an array?

Comment: You cannot change the return value of built-in functions. You are not showing how/where you call `.push` so all I can say is that `return ctx.email;` would return the array from a function.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes `ctx.emails` returns the empty array, and I want to store the email in there

Comment: Based on the information you provided you do/have `const newInvitationDto = {email: 'sethborne@gmail.com'}; const ctx = {emails: []}; ctx.emails.push(newInvitationDto.email); console.log(ctx.emails);`, which works perfectly fine (as you can test for yourself in the console). If it doesn't work for you then please provide a [mcve].